# Merge Join Operation in SQL Query costing 60%+ of query

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing, sql-execution-plan

I am trying to optimize a query that looks pretty simple but the merge query operation is taking the lion's share of the query time. I only am receiving about 1600 results a run and it's taking 25 seconds.  I am trying to get the cost and time of this down by 50%. I have tried to use the top 2000 trick to narrow down results and I made sure we are scanning all indexes. I know that seeks would be better but the scans are under 1% of the query.

Here is the plan and SQL.

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Ske3IIOQZ

[OrderApprovals_View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9j0Cs.png)

SQL for the view:

```
SELECT dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals.ApprovalID ,
   dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals.OrderID ,
   dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals.CLSItem ,
   dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals.CustNum ,
   dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals.ReqQuantity ,
   dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals.ReqShipDate ,
   dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals.UM ,
   dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals.CSR ,
   dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals.ShipLoc ,
   dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals.ApprovalType ,
   dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals.ApprovalGroup ,
   dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals.CreatedBy ,
   dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals.CreateDate ,
   dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals.CreatedPC ,
   dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals_SC_Notes.SC_Notes ,
   dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals_Status.Status ,
   CASE WHEN [Status] <> 'NEW' THEN SVC_OrderApprovals_Status.CreatedBy
        ELSE NULL
   END AS ReviewedBy ,
   CASE WHEN [Status] <> 'NEW' THEN SVC_OrderApprovals_Status.CreateDate
        ELSE NULL
   END AS ReviewDate ,
   CASE WHEN [Status] <> 'NEW' THEN SVC_OrderApprovals_Status.CreatedPC
        ELSE NULL
   END AS ReviewedPC ,
   dm_Core.dbo.core_CLSItemData.ItemDescription ,
   dm_Core.dbo.core_CustMaster.CustName ,
   dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals.SCTeam ,
   dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals_Status.CreateDate AS StatusCreateDate ,
   dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals_SC_Notes.CreateDate AS SCNoteCreateDate ,
   dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals_Approval_Notes.ApprovalNote ,
   dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals_Approval_Notes.CreateDate AS ApprovalNoteCreateDate
FROM   dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals_Current
   INNER JOIN dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals ON dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals_Current.RecordID = dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals.RecordID
   LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals_Approval_Notes ON dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals.ApprovalID = dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals_Approval_Notes.ApprovalID
   LEFT OUTER JOIN dm_Core.dbo.core_CustMaster ON dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals.CustNum = dm_Core.dbo.core_CustMaster.CustNum
   LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals_Status ON dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals.ApprovalID = dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals_Status.ApprovalID
   LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals_SC_Notes ON dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals.ApprovalID = dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals_SC_Notes.ApprovalID
   LEFT OUTER JOIN dm_Core.dbo.core_CLSItemData ON dbo.SVC_OrderApprovals.CLSItem = dm_Core.dbo.core_CLSItemData.CLSItem;
```

Comment: You should include the code for the view + create table clauses for any tables involved.

Comment: Yep. Without the view at the absolute minimum there is nothing anybody can do here. The table definition is almost certainly going to be needed too.

Comment: Looking at your plan, I can't tell what is trying to do the join. If you were to run the query again omitting one of the `where` conditions at a time, can you see which one is causing the issue? Is the view itself fast to return if you do a `select *` from it?

Comment: Ok so removing  `OR ApprovalType = CASE WHEN @HideCREDIT = 0 THEN 'Credit Hold' ELSE '' END ` this of course doesn't do much and 1600 results are still returned and the Merge Join is at 63%. Removing `AND ApprovalType NOT IN ('PIC Review','Credit Hold') ` keeps the merge join to 63%

Comment: A picture in this case is nearly worthless. What is worth a million words is the actual query that makes up the view.

Comment: @SeanLange added the query.

Comment: You can't rely on the percentage costs shown in the plan. They are estimates even in the actual plan and your estimated row count going into that is ludicrously inaccurate https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlbzC.png. A merge join of 6540 and 1667 rows is not accurately costed at 8,720,914,929 optimizer units

Comment: Is the view quick to return? Are there sensible indexes on each of the columns you are joining together?

Comment: @MartinSmith I believe this is the issue. There has to be something going on to create this and that is why it is taking 15-30 seconds to run 1000 rows. Is there a way to get SQL to cost this better or make the plan more align better?

Comment: @LordBaconPants The view is quick to return (under 3 seconds) normally. and this view returns 200K rows

Comment: Is this view pulling data from a bunch of other views? Those names sounds like they could very likely be views as well.

Comment: @SeanLange I will investigate the views, that is a very good point.

Comment: If those are in fact views that are selecting data from views that is very likely the basis of the performance issue. You can read more details about why nested views are so evil here. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven

Comment: @SeanLange - the paste the plan shows that if there are views involved (I haven't done an exhaustive comparison of table names shown there with those in the query) they are pretty simple.